# How to make a command line argument which rollsback to a specific version using FluentMigrator

Tags: visual-studio, github, fluent-migrator

I have added several tables in a project in Visual Studios. However, I want to rollback to a previous version using FluentMigrator. However, the Git website isn't very helpful when specifying which commands to use to rollback several versions: https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Command-Line-Runner-Options

If I do this command line arguement, will it revert the last 2 files I added? I added the command: "rollback:toversion -- version 2" but I'm not entirely sure if I'm using this right.

```
--conn "MyProject" --provider sqlserver --a "MyProject.DBMigrations\bin\Debug\MyProject.DBMigrations.dll" --task rollback:toversion --version 2  --verbose true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rollback 2 steps then set the task to `rollback` and use the `steps` switch.

```
--conn "MyProject" --provider sqlserver --a "MyProject.DBMigrations\bin\Debug\MyProject.DBMigrations.dll" --task rollback --steps 2  --verbose true
```

If you want to roll back to a specific version then use the the `rollback:toversion` task with the `version` switch. Then you set the version this refers to is the unique id in the migration attribute on a migration. In my case I use the datetime format for my migrations so todays date and time would be 201303062126.

```
    [Migration(201303062126)]
    public class CreateInitialDB : Migration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
         ...
```

And if I wanted to rollback to that specific version it would look like this:

```
--conn "MyProject" --provider sqlserver --a "MyProject.DBMigrations\bin\Debug\MyProject.DBMigrations.dll" --task rollback:toversion --version 201303062126
```

And what would happen is that all migrations that are newer than this migration would be rolled back but the migration 201303062126 would not be rolled back.

I'll update the wiki to make it clearer for the next person.